# Accessing super method from within a default method in an interface

Tags: java, interface, java-8

I was fiddling with Java 8 and came down to the following code which in my opinion *could* work:

```
class UnrelatedClass implements UnrelatedInterfaceDefault {
    @Override
    public void unrelate2() {
        System.out.println("Unrelated");
    }
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceDefault extends UnrelatedInterfaceOne, UnrelatedInterfaceTwo {
    default public void unrelate() {
        UnrelatedInterfaceOne.super.unrelate2();
        UnrelatedInterfaceTwo.super.unrelate2();
    }
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceOne {
    public void unrelate2();
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceTwo {
    public void unrelate2();
}
```

On `UnrelatedInterfaceOne.super.unrelate()`, I get the error:

```
abstract method unrelate2() in UnrelatedInterfaceOne cannot be accessed directly.
```

But consider if I would create a class that implements `UnrelatedInterfaceDefault`, then I actually *do* have implementations for `UnrelatedInterfaceOne` and `UnrelatedInterfaceTwo`, so it could work?

Why is there this specific compiler error in this case?

Comment: To make your example work as expected, you can use casts to the corresponding interfaces instead of invoking super. E.g. `((UnrelatedInterfaceOne)this).unrelate2();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is failing because the methods in your interfaces are `abstract`. If you make it `default`, then I guess it would compile. I can't test it right now though.

From [JLS §15.12.3 - Compile-Time Step 3: Is the Chosen Method Appropriate?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3):

> If the form is `TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then:
>
> - It is a compile-time error **if the compile-time declaration is `abstract`**.

Also note that, invocation of a method using `super` never goes through dynamic dispatch. It wouldn't invoke the overridden method, but only the method defined in the `super` class, or in this case `TypeName`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make your example work.

As noted @Rohit Jain I needed to change abstract-> default. Then I've got a [diamond problem](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/) right in `interface UnrelatedInterfaceDefault`. I resolved it with empty method.
That's all, it works. As for me, results are logical) see below

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        UnrelatedClass uc = new UnrelatedClass();
        uc.unrelate2();
        uc.unrelate();
    }
}

class UnrelatedClass implements UnrelatedInterfaceDefault {

    @Override
    public void unrelate2() {
        System.out.println("Unrelated");
    }
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceDefault extends UnrelatedInterfaceOne, UnrelatedInterfaceTwo {

    @Override
    public default void unrelate2() {
    }

    default public void unrelate() {
        UnrelatedInterfaceOne.super.unrelate2();
        UnrelatedInterfaceTwo.super.unrelate2();
        unrelate2();
    }
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceOne {

    public default void unrelate2() {
        System.out.println("relatedOne");
    }
}

interface UnrelatedInterfaceTwo {

    public default void unrelate2() {
        System.out.println("relatedTwo");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unrelated
relatedOne
relatedTwo
Unrelated
```